# Proving the existence of a supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$A=\{(1+(1/n))^n \mid n\text{ is taken from positive integers}\}$

How can I prove that the set above has a supremum? I've started with an assumption that

$(1+(1/n))^n < 3$ for every positive integer n

but I could not find a way to prove it too. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: Using the Binomial Theorem, we find that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}.$$
The term $\frac{1}{3!}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2^2}$. Continue.

Comment: I couldn't understand two points:
Why you used 'less or equal to' sign and how I can use the fact that  (1/3!) is less than (1/2^2).

Comment: It is mostly less than. We have the term $1/3!$ is less than $1/4$, the next term is less thn $1/8$, the next less than $1/16$, and so on, so the whole thing is less than $1+1+1/2+1/4+\cdots$ (finite sum), which is less than $1$ plus an infinite geometric series that sums to $2$. Have to go, if you have further questions I cannot answer them for 3 hours at least.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I understood. However, in the book that I am studying series is not treated before least upper bound axiom.

Comment: The least upper bound axiom is needed for the proof, for we have just shown the sequence is bounded. True, we are using a bit of information about series, but only that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^k}\lt 2$, which is high school material, the sum of the finite geometric series is exactly $(1-1/2^{k+1})(1-1/2)$, which is less than $2$.

Comment: http://sertoz.bilkent.edu.tr/courses/math113/2004/Ex12-p45.pdf
This also forms a proof for the existence of supremum of this set.